# Update a list after an item triggers its own deletion

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am rendering a card in a parent component for every post that a user has. In the card, all of the data is passed down via props. I have a delete axios call that works, however I have to manually refresh the page for the page to show updates.

Any way I can have it manually update the UI?

```
// DASHBOARD.JS
if (this.state.posts.length > 0 && this.state.loaded === true) {
  const posts = this.state.posts;

  content = posts.map(post => (
    <Card
      key={post._id}
      author={post.author}
      title={post.title}
      date={post.date}
      body={post.body}
      id={post._id}
    />
  ));
```

---

```
// CARD.JS
deleteOnClick = e => {
  axios
    .delete('http://localhost:5000/auth/deletePost', {
      params: {
        id: this.props.id
      }
    })
    .then(res => {
      console.log(res);
    })
    .catch(err => console.log(err));
  };
```

Comment: Define the deletion in the listing component (or the parent) and pass down a `deletePost(id)` type callback to the card. Then, the parent can both delete a post and update its own list.

Comment: Could you show a lot more of your code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you have two problems to fix in order to make this pattern work.

First thing first: avoid defining business logic in components used only for presentational purposes (have a read [here](https://medium.com/@dan_abramov/smart-and-dumb-components-7ca2f9a7c7d0)).
So in `Card` component there should be no explicit definition of the `deleteOnClick` method, while it should receive it from above in a dedicated prop of type `func`.

Second thing: the list component should handle the logic of deleting items from the list through the axios call and in the `then` statement you should think of a way to update the list items you are using to render `Card`s.

Examples in pseudocode:

List Component

```
import React from 'react';
import Card from './Card';

export default class List extends PureComponent {
  state = {
    items: [],
    error: null,
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    // add axios call to retrieve items data
  }

  deleteItemHandler = () => {
    axios
      .delete('http://localhost:5000/auth/deletePost', {
        params: {
          id: this.props.id
        }
      })
      .then(res => {
        this.setState({
          items: res.json(),
        })
      })
      .catch(err => {
        this.setState({
          error: err,
        })
      });
    };
  }

  render() {
    const { items } = this.state;
    return (
      <div>
        {items.map(item => (
          <Card
            {...item}
            onClick={this.deleteItemHandler}
          />
        ))}
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Card component:

```
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

export default class Card extends PureComponent {
  static propTypes = {
    title: PropTypes.string,
    // other props
    onClick: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  }

  // other things in this class

  render() {
    const { onClick, title } = this.props;
    return (
      <div onClick={onClick}>
        <h1>{title}</h1>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Once you get familiar with concept of separating logic and presentation you can start introducing [redux](https://react-redux.js.org/) and do things at another level :)

Hope this helps!